# Converting a "curl -X PUT ... - G ..." to python using the requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl, newrelic

I am attempting to write some python code to interact with New Relic's API. I'm using the requests module. For the most part I've been successful, but I'm having trouble with one API call. Their documentation represents the call with an example curl command:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/rest-api-alerts/new-relic-alerts-rest-api/rest-api-calls-new-relic-alerts
(under "Update notification channels associated with policies")

```
curl -X PUT 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_policy_channels.json' \
     -H 'X-Api-Key:{admin_api_key}' -i \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -G -d 'policy_id=policy_id&channel_ids=channel_id'
```

My main issue is that I am unclear how to translate the -G to python using the responses library. I'm not even totally sure I understand what that flag is doing, it sounds like it's making an additional get request in addition to the initial PUT?

I've been using this converter tool, which has worked for most curl calls I've been working with, but not this one.

https://curl.trillworks.com/

This is what's generated based off the above curl command (which does not work):

```
import requests

headers = {
    'X-Api-Key': '{admin_api_key}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = {
  'policy_id': 'policy_id',
  'channel_ids': 'channel_id'
}

response = requests.put('https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_policy_channels.json', headers=headers, data=data)
```

This is basically the same code, just wrapped in a function where I'm actually using it:

```
def set_alert_policy_notification_channel(admin_api_key, policy_id, notification_channel_id):
    headers = {
        'X-Api-Key': admin_api_key,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }

    data = {
    'policy_id': policy_id,
    'channel_ids': notification_channel_id
    }

    response = requests.put('https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_policy_channels.json', headers=headers, data=data)
    logging.debug(response)
    return response
```

When I make the call I'm getting 500 errors, probably because the request is not formed properly:

2019-07-11 09:35:31,546 - DEBUG - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.newrelic.com:443
 2019-07-11 09:35:32,046 - DEBUG - https://api.newrelic.com:443 "PUT /v2/alerts_policy_channels.json HTTP/1.1" 500 None
 2019-07-11 09:35:32,293 - DEBUG -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-G` in `curl` turns whatever you pass as `-d`/`--data` (and alike) into query params which are appended to the URL.

So, you need to pass the `data` as `params` in your PUT request with `requests`, not as `data`. Assmuming your current `headers` and `data` dicts:

```
response = requests.put('https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_policy_channels.json', headers=headers, params=data)
```

Note the `params=data` keyword argument.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and now the call succeeds. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

500 status code is an Internal Server Error, which means that the server cannot process the request for some unknown reason. My guess is that there is nothing wrong with your code, and that it is a server issue on their end... I did notice this on their site:

https://rpm.newrelic.com/api/explore/applications/update

> 500   A server error occurred, please contact New Relic support

Answer (score 0):

set data=json.dumps(data) instead of data=data

```
response = requests.put('https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_policy_channels.json', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```